# Using an insert statement with multiple withs

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have an SQL query (server 2012) which has multiple with statements to perform calculations on the initial result set.  Is there a way to perform an insert at each with statement into a temp table.

I can then perform a select at the end to see my results in a nice format.

Here is an example of the SQL code.  The real query is very long so didnt want to post it.  If there is a completely different way of doing this I am all ears.

```
with tce as (Select cash from sometable),
test1 as (((select * from tce) * 100) as morecash),
test 2 as (((select * from test1) * 100) as evenmorecash)
```

Comment: First - the `WITH` you refer to is a CTE or Common Table Expression.  This is a windowing function and depending on the way it is written can perform as poorly as a scalar function - so be careful!  Without seeing your code, there is no way for anyone here to tell you what is or isn't your best case.  Even then, we don't know your system, common load, number of users, server/database settings (parallelism, trace flags, etc).

Comment: Is that even valid syntax?  (select * from tce) * 100

Comment: why insert each cte into a temp table?   Why not just do a select from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expand your CTEs into temp table inserts:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT cash
INTO #temp1
FROM sometable;

-- Query 2
SELECT cash * 100 as morecash
INTO #temp2
FROM #temp1

-- Query 3
SELECT morecash * 100 as evenmorecash
INTO #temp3
FROM #temp2;

-- Output
SELECT *
FROM #temp3;
```